# How to import Matplotlib in C++ Makefile

Tags: c++, c++11, matplotlib, makefile

I used [this](https://readthedocs.org/projects/matplotlib-cpp/downloads/pdf/latest/) to download everything. I got the directory of where it was located and placed them in my makefile, but my compiler still gives an error that says-

```
matplotlibcpp.h: No such file or directory    
 #include "matplotlibcpp.h"
```

I am using C++11 and this is a very simple makefile. All I do is import header files that lead to one function in them. I just need to use matplotlib in main() anyway.

EDIT: I'm trying to install matplotlib in the server but this keeps popping up

```
>pip2 install python-matplotlib python-numpy python2.7-dev
Collecting python-matplotlib
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement python-matplotlib (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for python-matplotlib
```

Comment: See README https://github.com/Cryoris/matplotlib-cpp: `g++ minimal.cpp -std=c++11 -I/usr/include/python2.7 -lpython2.7`

Comment: It's not working, I edited in more details.

Comment: You should not use pip but apt-get if you are using ubuntu: `sudo apt-get install python-matplotlib python-numpy python2.7-dev`. What is your OS?

Comment: I honestly don't know. I'm on a windows computer but I'm ssh'ed into my school's linprog servers. I'm not allowed to install with sudo apt-get.

Comment: Find out that OS has the linprog server installed and then I can help you, otherwise I will not be able to do it.

Comment: The first comment is correct, but he specifically asked about makefile include and linking.